# libcurl compile and linker errors

Tags: c++-cli, compiler-errors, libcurl, linker-errors

I try to code an app with libcurl and c++-cli in visual studio c++. It gives me this error

```
error C3867: "fr::Form1::write_data": Dem Funktionsaufruf fehlt die Argumentliste. Verwenden Sie "&fr::Form1::write_data", um einen Zeiger auf den Member zu erstellen. c:\users\ttg\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\fr\fr\Form1.h
```

which means that I should pass some arguments to write_data. I don't know how to pass these data, and in the documentation of libcurl it shows exactly the same code that I have,which I just copy and pasted. I don't know what I need to add

Furthermore when I declare this write_data function outside of the Form I don't get this error but I get linker errors like:

```
Fehler  53  error LNK2031: p/invoke konnte nicht für ""extern "C" void __clrcall curl_easy_cleanup(void *)" (?curl_easy_cleanup@@$$J0YMXPAX@Z)" generiert werden. In den Metadaten fehlt die Aufrufkonvention.  fr.obj
```

meaning, missing call convetion in the metadata

This is my code:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace fr {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Zusammenfassung für Form1
    ///
    /// Warnung: Wenn Sie den Namen dieser Klasse ändern, müssen Sie auch
    ///          die Ressourcendateiname-Eigenschaft für das Tool zur Kompilierung verwalteter Ressourcen ändern,
    ///          das allen RESX-Dateien zugewiesen ist, von denen diese Klasse abhängt.
    ///          Anderenfalls können die Designer nicht korrekt mit den lokalisierten Ressourcen
    ///          arbeiten, die diesem Formular zugewiesen sind.
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Konstruktorcode hier hinzufügen.
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Verwendete Ressourcen bereinigen.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Designervariable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
        /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    public:
 size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
        {
           // assert(bodyfile == (FILE*) stream); //this assertion fails, but when i comment it, code works. Why?
            int written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
            return written;
        }
void proc(){
    CURL *curl_handle;
    const char *headerfilename = "head.out";
    FILE *headerfile;
    const char *bodyfilename = "body.html";
    FILE *bodyfile;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://url");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);

    /*this causes error*/curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

    headerfile = fopen(headerfilename,"w");
    if (headerfile == NULL) {
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
        return;
    }
    bodyfile = fopen(bodyfilename,"w");
    if (bodyfile == NULL) {
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
        return;
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle,   CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, headerfile);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, bodyfile);
    curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
    fclose(headerfile);
    fclose(bodyfile);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
    }//()proc 

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think write_data method should be made static... or outside Form class as you did... And about linker error: excerpt from msdn article [When attempting to import a native function into a pure image, remember that the implicit calling conventions differ between native and pure compilations.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173734%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: i generally have problems with those call conventions with __cdecl and clr/pure, not only with this write_data function, but as I have seen by changing some things, I get same errors with functions from the libcurl library, which was compiled from c files. Do you think there are any settings that I should change in visual studio so that this compiles, because the whole project worked in dev c++, and I only need to add a GUI.

Comment: @Tasos Papanikolaou sorry but from you response I don't understand if you had added /clr:pure to compile options in VisualStudio then you where compiling your project and as I understand you also should use __cdecl then you declare native function for example extern "C" int __cdecl func();